# nginx configuration to serve multiple sites (subdomains) from same server

Tags: sockets, nginx, flask, routes, uwsgi

I would like to serve multiple sites from the same machine.

For each site, I am using nginx listening to a port to communicate with app server (uwsgi) and another port as a proxy server.
Each site uses uwsgi and flask.

All sites share same API ending point names, so the only difference will be the subdomain name.

Something like this:

```
server {

    listen 8000 default_server;

    server_name 00.myexample.com;

    ...

}

# Set cache dir
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:10m max_size=50m inactive=60m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";


# Virtualhost/server configuration
server {
    listen  80  default_server;

    server_name 00.myexample.com;

    location / {

        proxy_cache my_zone;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://00.myexample.com:8000;
    }

...

}
```

I thought, to replicate multiple sites (00.myexample.com, 01.myexample.com) I would just need to make listen to different ports.

Are `server_name` and a different ports sufficient to avoid conflicts (e.g. in the cached) ?
Should also uwsgi listen to different ports for each app ? (it communicate with nginx through socket in the folder of each site, now)

Which configuration would you do to route multiple subdomains to a same machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `server` blocks in your conf file, and as long as the `server_name` is different in each one they will be treated distinctly. If the backend for each subdomain is exactly the same, you can use the same value for `proxy_pass` for each `server` block. Otherwise you would have to run a process for each backend and have it listen on a different port.

Comment: when using the same server, you "can use the same value for proxy_pass for each server block."  By value, do you mean listening to the same port? e.g. `server { server_name 00.. location  / {proxy_pass http://00.myexample.com:8000; } ..} #and server { server_name 01 .. location / { proxy_pass http://01.myexample.com:8000; } .. }` ? Won't it conflict with the nginx cache? Can I route server names to same IP machine but on different ports? e.g. 00.example.com A domain on XX.XXX.XX.XXX:8000,  01.example.com XX.XXX.XX.XXX:7000 ? which port are "generally" free?